# When do we have equality in Jensen's inequality?

Tags: calculus, jensen-inequality

I'm talking about the finite form of the inequality:

> $$f(q_1x_1+q_2x_2+\cdots+q_nx_n)\leq q_1f(x_1)+q_2f(x_2)+\cdots+q_nf(x_n)$$
>   with
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{q_i}=1, q_i\geq 0$$
>   (Obviously the form for convex functions.)

I'm just wondering when does the equality happen.

Comment: If $f$ is linear, you have equality.

Comment: Just draw a picture, it explains everything for 2 variables. Equality for Jensen's inequality is analogous

Comment: If this means for ALL $q_1,\ldots, q_n$ for which $q_1+\cdots+q_n=1$ and for ALL $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb R,$ then it would be better to say so. Also, isn't it normally assumed that $q_i\ge0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: I'm sorry.I'm going to add everything.

Answer (score 6):

One way equality can occur is if $x_1 = \cdots = x_n$. Another way the equality can occur is if $f$ is linear.

Comment: @Denis-GeorgeMih Yes, that's right.